# Collapsing Toolbar Layout and Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-constraintlayout, overlapping

I am struggling to create collapsing image header alongside Constraint where my design looks like this

[image]

Currently the profile pic is a part of the `ConstraintLayout` because it needs Guideline constraints and unfortunately it is overlapped by the `AppBarLayout`

Any ideas how to achieve that? 
Can't find any source regarding my combination of layouts.....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/playerViewBg"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bgIV"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/header_bg" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/playerIV"
            android:layout_width="177dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/profilePic"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <!-- Other content -->

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.27" />

          <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.73" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Following is the snippet of my working layout:

Please make sure that you haven't make any childview height to match parent(0 dp) inside constrianlayout also for scroll view `android:fillViewport="true"`. Ask me if any doubt Occur.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivImagec"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_90sdp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/no_des"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/outdoorgames" />


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_90sdp"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/cvLayout"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
                 ....
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've actually recently started thinking about this

And based on this talk here from two of the devs behind Android Studio :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lAXJ5NFXTM (at the 21 mins: 28 seconds mark)

[image: Nicol's demo]

It is definitely possible, they recommend replacing the CollapsingToolbarLayout completely with the ConstraintLayout.

Comment: 10x I will give it a look it sure looks promising :) Actually I've solved the issue moving the constraint to the collapse.

Comment: @JockyDoe can you explain little more ?

Comment: @JockyDoe ya, In above-mentioned youtube talks, they didn't shared any sort of source code of demo examples explained in ppt/demo! (you can answer your own question :) ;)   )

Comment: @LOG_TAG well I didn't solved by what's in the youtube video but if you're that interested I might post what I came up with.
Is your goal to shrink image with the collapse bar?

Comment: @JockyDoe Yes, with Title Subtitle (I have fully work old code but i want o try it in CL)  P.S: I hate tech talks demos without a link to samples showed in the tech talks !!

Comment: @LOG_TAG ok I will make an example in the next days and will let you know when it's ready

Comment: @JockyDoe that will be great, also let me know if you find this is code anywhere (https://j.gifs.com/APrX7p.gif)

Comment: Hey do you guys find any solution?

Comment: @ibhavikmakwana Yes from your repo :D Constraint-Layout-Animations, great work!

Comment: For those of you interested in soruces & written explination of the above video: https://medium.com/google-developers/introduction-to-motionlayout-part-i-29208674b10d