# Is there any alternative for MotionLayout to create collapsible header with ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-motionlayout

I created a layout using constraint layout where the body view (viewpager for fragments) depend on header (e.g., viewpager has property layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button1" where button1 is view at the very bottom of header). Now I need to create animation like collapsible header, but I got some issue with CollapsingToolbarLayout because viewpager and the header is connecting and I think I need ConstraintLayout to do that, not CoordinatorLayout.

I did some research and found droidcon video that explain about using ConstraintLayout to replace the CollapsingToolbarLayout in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47999100/11986468) . I tried to implement it but it's not exactly what I need because it just let me create the header using ConstraintLayout while I need ConstraintLayout as the root layout. I need to set onClickListener button1 (in header) from activity and I can't do that if I put the button in 2 different layout (in header_open.xml and header_close.xml). *or i'm missing something and I actually can do that?*

I another way to create collapsible header using MotionLayout, it works perfect just like what I want because I just want to change visibility and constraints for some views in the header. But MotionLayout need dependency ConstraintLayout 2.0 and unfotunately I found bug in one of the devices I use to test (pages that use ConstraintLayout is messed up).

**Is there any alternative I can use that works just like MotionLayout but using dependency ConstraintLayout 1.xx ?**
May be using constraintset and transition?

p.s. I tried to use constraint set and transition manager but all examples and explanation that I found use onClickListener to trigger animation or layout changes (from constrainset 1 to 2) while I need scroll to trigger the changes) I think I can use constraint set and transition if I know what can I use to trigger changes with behavior like `<OnSwipe>` in Motion Layout. So my question can be **"Is there any alternative I can use that works just like `<OnSwipe>` in MotionLayout?"**

**or may be someone can tell me why pages that use ConstraintLayout messed up when using dependency `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-rc1`?**

My code with collapsing constraint layout still got some errors, so I will just put my code with MotionLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/scene_activity_main"
    tools:context=".presentation.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgHeader"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_header"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_35dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_back"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btnHistory"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_8dp"
        android:text="@string/label_history"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_12sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imgBanner" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_12dp"
        android:text="@string/label_text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/imgBanner"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgBanner"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_203dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_35dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgHeader"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imgHeader"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_rounded_primary"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_47dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_47dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_point"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imgBanner"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imgBanner"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imgBanner" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgBanner"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imgBanner"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgBanner"
        tools:text="100" />

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_primary_tab"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnHistory">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorTransparent"
            android:paddingVertical="@dimen/dimen_8dp"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/bg_primary_tab"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicator="@drawable/bg_indicator_tab"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorGrey19"
            app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="true"
            app:tabIndicatorGravity="center"
            app:tabInlineLabel="true"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabRippleColor="@null"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/CustomTextAppearanceTab">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_play"
                android:text="@string/label_tab1" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_coin"
                android:text="@string/label_tab2" />

        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

Here is my scene code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <Transition
        app:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        app:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
        app:duration="500"
        app:motionInterpolator="linear">

        <OnSwipe
            app:dragDirection="dragUp"
            app:touchAnchorId="@id/viewPager"
            app:touchAnchorSide="top" />
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint android:id="@+id/btnHistory">
            <PropertySet android:visibility="visible" />
        </Constraint>

        <Constraint android:id="@+id/tvLabel">
            <PropertySet android:visibility="visible" />
        </Constraint>

        <Constraint android:id="@+id/imgBanner">
            <Layout
                android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_203dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_35dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgHeader"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imgHeader" />
        </Constraint>

        <Constraint android:id="@+id/imgIcon">
            <Layout
                android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_47dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_47dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imgBanner"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imgBanner"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imgBanner" />
        </Constraint>

        <Constraint android:id="@+id/viewPager">
            <Layout
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_24dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnHistory" />
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint android:id="@+id/btnHistory">
            <PropertySet android:visibility="invisible" />
        </Constraint>

        <Constraint android:id="@+id/tvLabel">
            <PropertySet android:visibility="invisible" />
        </Constraint>

        <Constraint android:id="@+id/imgBanner">
            <Layout
                android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_176dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_35dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btnBack"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/btnBack" />
        </Constraint>

        <Constraint android:id="@+id/imgIcon">
            <Layout
                android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_35dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_35dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imgBanner"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imgBanner"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imgBanner" />
        </Constraint>

        <Constraint android:id="@+id/viewPager">
            <Layout
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_16dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgBanner" />
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

*I use bold for my questions in case my explanation is confusing. Sorry for my grammar, english is not my first language. I open for all suggestion related to this problem (even just links to some references would be appreciated). Thankyou in advance.*

Comment: Both of your problems with `CollapsingToolbarLayout` (your 1. and 2.) are solvable problems (the first isn't a problem at all - any layouts can be in a CollapsingToolbarLayout). You should include enough code in your question to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thankyou for your feedback, I realize my first concern is not really a problem, so I edited my question and added some code to help you understand my question better

Answer (score 1):

Because no one has answer this question yet, I decided to put my solution here, if any of you have any suggestion or better approach for this question, please tell me.

I couldn't find the alternative for MotionLayout, so I end up using CollapsingToolbarLayout for this. Fortunately, I can get the UI that I want after several trials and found the code to create smooth scroll animation with the layout I want. I found this code in stackoverflow, sorry I can't put the reference because I forgot to add a bookmark to the link.

```
val offsetChangedListener =
        AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener { _, verticalOffset ->
            if (collapsingToolbar.height + verticalOffset < collapsingToolbar.scrimVisibleHeightTrigger) {
                //COLLAPSE
                //set layout params
            } else {
                //EXPAND
                //set layout params                    
            }
        }
    appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(offsetChangedListener)
```

And this is final code for my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context=".presentation.MainActivity">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgHeader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/bg_header"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription,VectorDrawableCompat" />

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorTransparent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:elevation="@dimen/dimen_0dp">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/dimen_60dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnBack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_35dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_back"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription,VectorDrawableCompat" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintHeader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btnHistory"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_8dp"
                android:text="@string/label_history"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_12sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imgBanner" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_12dp"
                android:text="@string/label_text"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/imgBanner"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgBanner"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_203dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_121dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/bg_rounded_primary"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_47dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_47dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_point"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imgBanner"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imgBanner"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imgBanner" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgBanner"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imgBanner"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgBanner"
                tools:text="100" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_24dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_primary_tab"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorTransparent"
        android:paddingVertical="@dimen/dimen_8dp"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/bg_primary_tab"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIconTint="@color/colorGray40"
        app:tabIndicator="@drawable/bg_grey19_tab"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorGrey19"
        app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="true"
        app:tabIndicatorGravity="center"
        app:tabInlineLabel="true"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabRippleColor="@null"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/CustomTextAppearanceTab">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tab1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_play"
            android:text="@string/label_redeem_voucher" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tab2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_coin"
            android:text="@string/label_challenge" />

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
</androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I think this is better than create 2 layout file for header collapse and expand because as I mention in question, I need 1 layout file so I can set onClickListener to button in header.

Comment: Can you post the output of this code ?